# UIRefreshControl doesn't show spiny when "Adjust Scroll View Insets" is deselected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UIView with a UIScrollView and a content view embedded in a UINavigationController. I added a UIRefreshControl to the Scroll View.

At first I had the problem that the content was shown in the wrong position, not as I set it in Interface Builder.
At this time, the Refresh Control was still working fine without problems.

But after I had solved  that first problem by deselecting 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' in the attributes inspector of my View Controller, the Refresh Control does not show the spiny any more. I already tried changing the Scroll View's inset at the beginning of refreshing but it didn't help. Here's the code I already wrote:

In viewDidLoad:

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(beginRefreshingView)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Then in beginRefreshingView:

```
[self.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(refreshControl.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0)];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
```

Would be great if anybody could give me any answers or suggestions. Maybe there's another way to solve the first problem without deselecting 'Adjust Scroll View Insets'?

Comment: please post what piece of code you already have done and where specifically there is a problem.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier thanks for your answer I've done it but it is not much code I only can tell you that the first part worked fine before deselecting 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' and all the other stuff was done in Interface Builder.